# How to make itemize/enumerate/description environment start from right to left?

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, polyglossia, arabic

Does anyone know how to make itemize/enumerate/description environment start from right to left ?

i read this documentation: [Enumitem](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/archive/enumitem.pdf) but with no luck

```
 \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Scheherazade}

\begin{document}

Some latin text and inline arabic: \textarabic{السلام عليكم}
\begin{itemize}[label=$\heartsuit$]
\item pomme ;
\item radis ;
\item choucroute.
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[font=\color{magenta} \Large, rightmargin=6cm, label=\ding{45}]
\item \textarabic{تفاحة} ;
\item \textarabic{فجل} ;
\item \textarabic{ملفوف مخلل}.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `bidi` package offers the `RTLitems` environment for this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Scheherazade}

\begin{document}

Some latin text and inline arabic: \textarabic{السلام عليكم}
\begin{itemize}[label=$\heartsuit$]
\item pomme ;
\item radis ;
\item choucroute.
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[font=\color{magenta} \Large,label=\ding{45}]
\begin{RTLitems}
\item \textarabic{تفاحة} ;
\item \textarabic{فجل} ;
\item \textarabic{ملفوف مخلل}.
\end{RTLitems}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]