# List bullet points on the right side

Tags: lists, bullets

In html I can use the dir keyword to move the bullet points to the right side of the item:

```
<ul dir="rtl">
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">Jewel Thieves</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Community</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zbx0p65h/3/

Is there an equivalent command for a latex [list](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-260.html)?

Comment: maybe have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235698/rtl-beamer-getting-lists-to-right-align or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229106/how-to-make-itemize-enumerate-description-environment-start-from-right-to-left

Comment: The suggestions in the links above also reverse the typesetting of the item to right to left. I only want to move the bullet point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to patch several internal `list`-related commands, but yes, it can be done:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\makelistright{%
    \leftmargin\z@
    \patchcmd{\@listi}%
        {\leftmargin\leftmargini}%
        {\rightmargin\leftmargini}%
        {}{}%
    \patchcmd{\@listii}%
        {\leftmargin\leftmarginii}%
        {\rightmargin\leftmarginii}%
        {}{}%
    \patchcmd{\@listiii}%
        {\leftmargin\leftmarginiii}%
        {\rightmargin\leftmarginiii}%
        {}{}%
    \patchcmd{\@listiv}%
        {\leftmargin\leftmarginiv}%
        {\rightmargin\leftmarginiv}%
        {}{}%
    \patchcmd{\@listv}%
        {\leftmargin\leftmarginv}%
        {\rightmargin\leftmarginv}%
        {}{}%
    \patchcmd{\@listvi}%
        {\leftmargin\leftmarginvi}%
        {\rightmargin\leftmarginvi}%
        {}{}%
    \patchcmd{\@trivlist}%
        {%
            \leftskip\z@skip%
            \rightskip\@rightskip%
            \parfillskip\@flushglue%
        }%
        {%
            \leftskip\@flushglue%
            \rightskip\@rightskip%
            \parfillskip\z@skip%
        }%
        {}{}%
    \patchcmd{\@item}%
        {\box\@labels}%
        {%
            \hskip-\@flushglue%
            \hbox to 0pt {\hskip\linewidth\box\@labels\hskip-\linewidth}%
            \hskip\@flushglue%
        }%
        {}{}%
    \patchcmd{\@item}%
        {%
            \unhbox\@labels
            \hskip \itemindent
            \hskip -\labelwidth
            \hskip -\labelsep
            \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\labelwidth
            \box\@tempboxa
            \else
                \hbox to\labelwidth {\unhbox\@tempboxa}%
            \fi
            \hskip \labelsep
        }%
        {%
            \hskip \labelsep%
            \hbox to\labelwidth {\unhbox\@tempboxa}%
            \unhbox\@labels
            \hskip -\labelwidth
            \hskip -\labelsep
        }%
        {}{}%
    \def\@mklab##1{##1\hss}%
    \patchcmd{\itemize}%
        {\hss\llap}%
        {}%
        {}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{makelistright}

\begin{itemize}
\item Home
\item Jewel Thieves
\item Community
\end{itemize}

\end{makelistright}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3):

A `tabular` can be used, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{\quad}>{\textbullet}c@{}}
  Home &\\
  Jewel Thieves &\\
  Community &\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: That works, but it's a tabular not a [list](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-260.html). Still looking for the list option.